# Including a Ruby module before or after ActiveRecord associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to define fetcher methods for Rails models depending on their associations:

```
module Fetchers
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    reflect_on_all_associations.each do |association|
      define_method "fetch_#{association.name}" do
        # do something
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and include this module in models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Fetchers

  belongs_to :team
  has_many :projects
end
```

so that I can get methods such as `User#fetch_team` and `User#fetch_projects`.

But for the module to list the model's associations, it needs to be included after them, which leads to awkward code like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include CoolStuff
  include CommonMethods

  belongs_to :team
  has_many :projects

  include Fetchers

  scope :something, ->{ where(something: true) }

  after_save :do_this

  ...
end
```

Is there a way to make the Fetchers module wait for the class associations to be defined first before generating the methods?

Comment: I dont think so ruby code is executed on the fly, in the order its written